Using Import csv and foreach to duplicate template to multiple sharepoint sites
I have a question about SharePoint online. Our project assignment is to make new sites for our client. We want to design a script that makes it easier to use a template and add that to a site. I have made this code to make the template
PS C:\WINDOWS\System32>  Connect-SPOService -Url https://lk6y-admin.sharepoint.com
>> $site_script = '
>>  {
>>    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/site-design-script-actions.schema.json",
>>      "actions": [
>>        {
>>          "verb": "createSPList",
>>          "listName": "Customer Tracking",
>>          "templateType": 100,
>>          "subactions": [
>>            {
>>              "verb": "setDescription",
>>              "description": "List of Customers and Orders"
>>            },
>>            {
>>              "verb": "addSPField",
>>              "fieldType": "Text",
>>              "displayName": "Customer Name",
>>              "isRequired": false,
>>              "addToDefaultView": true
>>            },
>>            {
>>              "verb": "addSPField",
>>              "fieldType": "Number",
>>              "displayName": "Requisition Total",
>>              "addToDefaultView": true,
>>              "isRequired": true
>>            },
>>            {
>>              "verb": "addSPField",
>>              "fieldType": "User",
>>              "displayName": "Contact",
>>              "addToDefaultView": true,
>>              "isRequired": true
>>            },
>>            {
>>              "verb": "addSPField",
>>              "fieldType": "Note",
>>              "displayName": "Meeting Notes",
>>              "isRequired": false
>>            }
>>          ]
>>        }
>>      ]
>>  }
>>  '
PS C:\WINDOWS\System32>  Connect-SPOService -Url https://lk6y-admin.sharepoint.com
>> Add-SPOSiteScript -Title "bruh" -Content $site_script -Description "Creates list"


Id                  : 6fa8f5ec-02ed-4764-877e-d3fae0732326
Title               : bruh
Description         : Creates list
Content             :
Version             : 0
IsSiteScriptPackage : False

PS C:\WINDOWS\System32> Add-SPOSiteDesign -Title "bruh" -Webtemplate "64" -SiteScripts "6fa8f5ec-02ed-4764-877e-d3fae0732326" -Description "Tracks key customer data"


Id                  : 002be403-d8bd-4701-b5c3-f1741e234ba4
Title               : bruh
WebTemplate         : 64
SiteScriptIds       : {6fa8f5ec-02ed-4764-877e-d3fae0732326}
Description         : Tracks key customer data
ThumbnailUrl        :
PreviewImageUrl     :
PreviewImageAltText :
IsDefault           : False
Version             : 1
DesignPackageId     : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
DesignType          : Site

The code I made makes a new template. I want to write the import csv and foreach functions into this code to make it possible to add the template to multiple sites at once. Im very new at Powershell I could really use some help.

In the code you have written, what changes for each site?

as an alternative, you can use a template engine, like one I wrote.  https://github.com/DCressey/Expand-Csv/blob/master/Expand-Csv.ps1
